# How to make a python instanced object reusable?

Tags: python

a couple of my python programs aim to

1. format into a hash table (hence, I'm a dict() addict ;-) ) some informations in a "source" text file, and
2. to use that table to modify a "target" file. My concern is that the "source" files I usually process can be very large (several GB) so it makes more than 10sec to parse, and I need to run that program a bunch of times. To conclude, I feel like it's a waste to reload the same large file each time I need to modify a new "target".

My thought is, if it would be possible to write once the dict() made from the "source" file in a way that python would be able to read/process much faster (I think about a format close to the one used in RAM by python), it would be great.

Is there a possibility to achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yea, you can [`marshal`](http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html) the dict, or you can use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-pickle). For the difference between the two, especially as regards to speed, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329249/why-is-marshal-so-much-faster-than-pickle).

Comment: In addition, that works very efficiently (I tried only Marshal)!

Answer (score 0):

`pickle` is the usual solution to such things, but if you see any value in being able to edit the saved data, and if the dictionary uses only simple types such as strings and numbers (nested dictionaries or lists are also OK), you can simply write the `repr()` of the dictionary to a text file, then parse it back into a Python dictionary using `eval()` (or, better yet, `ast.literal_eval()`).

Comment: this won't be very fast though

Comment: Faster than parsing it from the original file, slower than `pickle`.

Comment: Marshal fits perfectly my needs. I appreciate your answer though, I might use it in the future. Thanks.